# Intelligently Controlling 5 PTAC Units

Tags: heating, air-conditioning, home-automation, nest

I recently purchased a new apartment which comes with GE zoneline PTAC units that control both heating and air conditioning electrically. There are a total of 5 in my apartment, 1 for each bedroom and 2 in our living room and kitchen (which for some reason are right next to each other, not sure if that is necessary but that's a different problem.)

Here's the manual:
https://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=20-S0046.pdf

My question is how can I control them all at once with smartphone tech and is it even worth it to leave them on all at once all the time. I'm also unsuredon't if there is even a centralized way that can control all of them at once at all via any thermostat Nest or otherwise. GE has sent me the manual but it seems to allude that it can control only one unit (really made for hotel rooms).

I also have a google home hub that I think may be able to integrate everything I have for other smart home products (very new at all this smarthome tech) including this.

I found via reddit, a link to two products which may help, but am not sure if 5 of them can be used at once or if this is even compatible with google home hub or if it comes with its own app:

https://shop.thinkecoinc.com/products/wifi-smartac-kit#.XEkams9Khi9

https://store.idevicesinc.com/idevices-switch/

but the question remains, can I do 5 at once all centralized into my Google Home Hub?

Any help or leads would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jordan

Answer (score 2):

Page 17 of the manual linked in the question has the information you need to wire up remote thermostats, that is, to connect wall thermostats rather than using the control panel on the unit.  You will have to run five, six, or seven conductor thermostat cable (depending on the unit) from each unit to its thermostat.

You could follow those instructions to install multiple smart thermostats to control multiple units with the smart thermostat app.  There are also instructions to control two units with a single thermostat (twinning) so you don't necessarily have to install five thermostats to control five units.